# The App Name you entered has already been used. Republish

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, mobile-development

I'm going to create a completely new app for the customer. The problem has occurred when I was trying to create an iTunes Connect Record for this new app I got an error "The App Name you entered has already been used". Because the customer already has an older app with the same name form before. 
How can I publish new app rewritten from scratch with the same name now? Couldn't find any info  on iTunes Connect Developer Guide.

Comment: You could a. submit this version as an update to the existing app or b. choice a new name. Adding something like V2 to the name should already work.

Comment: Did you try with the bundle identifier of the previous app? This would act as an upgrade of the old app.

Comment: @rckoenes Existing app was published by some other developer. Is there any form to submit some kind of doc where my client approve my rights to use the name and a logo from an older app? There is one on Google play.

Comment: you can ask the old developer to transfer you this app

Comment: @TommyBs so there is a possibility to transfer an app from one developer to another? Do you have any links with details about how to do that, and how does it work?

Comment: Are you talking about developers or iTunesConnect account. If you have acces to the client iTunesConnect account and see the old app there you should also see it on the Apple Developers page. You can now just grab the provisioning profile and use the same Bundle ID to submit a new version of the app. If the app is in some other account you will need to transfer it to the new account.

Comment: You will need the developer of the current app to transfer it to you - quick google search results in this page https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/TransferringAndDeletingApps.html I'd then suggest your client actually sets up their own itunesconnect account so they don't run into this situation again and they own the app. They should then just grant you access to their account rather then it sit in your account